# flexbox - last box heigher than others

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a problem with flexbox. The last box in a row has more height than others. I see that if I give specific height to the boxes I will achieve the same height on the boxes but since I am trying to make responsive site I wondering it is better way to define height and not using px sizing. The boxes including images and text inside. I have tried to put % on the height but it doesn't change anything. What is the best way to use in this case to avoid many jobs in media query later? is the px the only solution?

Thank you in advance

the boxes look like this:

Code:

```css
.footer-box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  flex-wrap:wrap; // using wrap for wraping on smaller devices
}

.box {
  text-align: center;
  width:20%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer-box">
    <div class="box box1">
      <img src="./images/other/pic1.jpg" alt="">
      <p>lorem text</p>
    </div>

    <div class="box box2">
      <img src="./images/other/pic1.jpg" alt="">
      <p>lorem text</p>
    </div>

    <div class="box box3">
      <img src="./images/other/pic1.jpg" alt="">
      <p>lorem text</p>
    </div>

    <div class="box box4">
      <img src="./images/other/pic1.jpg" alt="">
      <p>lorem text</p>
    </div>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Hi, I haven't tested this myself, but would it not be simpler to use 'vh' (for the height) and 'vw' (for the width) units of measurements. I am not extremely well versed in html and CSS, so not quite sure if this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can use flexbox and `flex-direction:column` for `.box`.
- Also you should use `align-items: stretch` for `.footer-box`. Because all child items will have same heights with this code.
- Lastly, through `flex: 1 1 auto;` we can fill with img.

And bonus: `object-fit: cover` is for your img sizes.

```css
.footer-box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  flex-wrap: wrap; // using wrap for wraping on smaller devices
  align-items: stretch;
}

.box {
  text-align: center;
  width: 20%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.box img {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer-box">

  <div class="box box1">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/50x50/000/fff" alt="">
    <p>lorem text</p>
  </div>

  <div class="box box2">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/50x50/000/fff" alt="">
    <p>lorem text</p>
  </div>

  <div class="box box3">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/50x50/000/fff" alt="">
    <p>lorem text</p>
  </div>

  <div class="box box4">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/50x70/000/fff" alt="">
    <p>lorem text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Afife
First of all, thank you for your answer. This is not helping me much because i can now see that my(and yours) code works like it shold but im still haveing the same problem. 
Last div (box4) is still litlebit higher than others. I cant understand why. I have just copied my and yours code into CodePen and all divs are the same size but on my page that is not the case...I really cant understand what is the problem :/

Comment: it seams like  the last box always have bigger size than the others. I just reduced to 3 boxes and than the 3th box is bigger.. 
someone who might have an idea what the reason for this is?

Comment: @VP actually it can work if the codes I added are implemented in its own code. Because If you remove the codes that I listed from the code that I wrote, the height of the end box seems too high like your case. You can check on this site: https://codepen.io/afife/pen/JjEYvWr
If you share more details, for example container, img src est., maybe we can understand better.

Comment: @AfifeBetui 
I am sorry, maybe i wasnt clear in the description of the problem. The last box is not higher because i want to have higher image. It is higher even when i am suing the same image for all boxes. And it only heppening on together with the rest of the code i have on the page. It seems like that is something in the rest of the code what making this problem. I have even tried deleting everything above and below the footer-box container and problem is still there.. if i add the the 5th box just to trick the browser and add the display:none, its working. But it is not the best solution

Comment: I understand, but I can not solve your problem without checking your code. I am thinking and maybe there is :last-child pseudo class. @VP